# POST function in RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

I want to POST a file to an API by RestSharp, but the `Method.Post` encounter error as *cannot convert from 'RestSharp.Method' to 'string?'*, and the error for the `Method.POST` is *'Method' does not contain a definition for 'POST'*?

```
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace UploadToAzure
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:7071/api/Function1");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddFile("File", "/D:/sample Files/audio0001.mp3");
            IRestResponse response = (IRestResponse)client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: `RestRequest` probably takes a string that is a URL as an argument but you are giving it a `Method`. Check the documentation and samples to see how to use `RestRequest`

Comment: What is the version of RestSharp?

Comment: how can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, but solved it by  doing the following two things

1. Changed POST to Post.
2. Putting Method.Post in double quotes "", i.e treating it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

It solved when I add string of destination to *RestRequest* and change *IRestResponse* to *RestResponse*. In addition correct the path of file.

```
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace UploadToAzure
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:7071/api/Function1");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddFile("File", @"D:/sample Files/audio0001.mp3");
            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IRestResponse is deprecated.  Use RestResponse instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).